# No handles with labels found to put in legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I'm trying to create a parallelogram in PyPlot. I'm not up to drawing the parallelogram--first I'm putting in the vector arrows--using the following code:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
plt.axis([-5,5,-5,5])
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
plt.grid()
plt.arrow(0,0, 3,1, head_width=0.2, color='r', length_includes_head=True, label='u')
plt.arrow(0,0, 1,3, head_width=0.2, color='r', length_includes_head=True, label='v')
plt.arrow(0,0, 4,4, head_width=0.2, color='r', length_includes_head=True, label='u+v')
plt.legend()
```

This returns the following error:

```
No handles with labels found to put in legend.
```

I'm not sure why, because, based on the documentation for `plt.arrow()`, `label` is an acceptable kwarg, and `plt.legend()` should ostensibly be reading that. The rest of the figure draws fine; it's just missing the legend.

Comment: For some reason, I cannot reproduce this error. After including the import statement, I can run this code with any errors and it displays the legend.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It might be late but for anyone with the same issue the solution is using the method `legend()` for the corresponding `ax` not as for `plt`

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
plt.axis([-5,5,-5,5])
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
plt.grid()
plt.arrow(0,0, 3,1, head_width=0.2, color='r', length_includes_head=True, label='u')
plt.arrow(0,0, 1,3, head_width=0.2, color='r', length_includes_head=True, label='v')
plt.arrow(0,0, 4,4, head_width=0.2, color='r', length_includes_head=True, label='u+v')
ax.legend()
```

Comment: Its very easy to forget that you have subplots. Thanks for this. Really helped me out.

Answer (score 26):

You can explicitly define the elements in the legend.

> For full control of which artists have a legend entry, it is possible to pass an iterable of legend artists followed by an iterable of legend labels respectively. [Reference](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html)

Example:

```
arr1 = plt.arrow(0,0, 3,1, head_width=0.2, color='r', length_includes_head=True)
arr2 = plt.arrow(0,0, 1,3, head_width=0.2, color='g', length_includes_head=True)
arr3 = plt.arrow(0,0, 4,4, head_width=0.2, color='b', length_includes_head=True)

plt.xlim(0,5)
plt.ylim(0,5)

plt.legend([arr1, arr2, arr3], ['u','v','u+v'])
```

[image]

Comment: That being said, shouldn't the legend be working with the labels provided in the `plt.arrow()`s?

Comment: @Yehuda Yes, plt.arrow() works like plt.plot(), and that is being asked for. It is strange why this solution is upvoted so much since it does not explain why plt.legend() does not understand the setting of the label in plt.arrow(), although it should. If it is the same way as in plt.plot(), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66862848/no-handles-with-labels-found-to-put-in-legend-error-after-plotting-two-plots-on or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64555759/no-handles-with-labels-found-to-put-in-legend-linechart.

Comment: @questionto42 1. Thanks for the links and the answers 2. This was the only answer available for almost a year, hence the upvotes ;)

Answer (score 8):

The error is thrown because you haven't specified the label text

Either do something like this

```
plt.hist([x01, x02,x03], color=["lightcoral","lightskyblue","slategrey"], stacked=True, 
             label=['Supressed','Active','Resolved'])
plt.legend()
```

Or

Do ***not*** use plt.legend() ***if you haven't specified the label text*** as in the following ***WRONG example***:

```
plt.hist([x01])
plt.legend()
```

**The above will throw the same error**, so either remove legend function or provide what it needs -> label.
Side note: Here x01 is just a list of number for which I am creating a histogram, in the first example they are three list of numbers to create stacked bar chart

The bottom line is this error is thrown because of not specifying legend text and calling/initializing a legend

Comment: Each arrow has a specified label though.

Answer (score 5):

I had this error when using labels which started with an underscore

`plt.plot(x, y,  label = '_bad_name')`

Removing the front underscore from the labels solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have 2 plots ax and ax2, we can:

- get the labels from each y-axis via `ax.get_label()`
- `.legend` allows an array to be ingested

```
fig.legend([ax.get_ylabel(), ax2.get_ylabel()], loc='upper right')
```

Answer (score -1):

I face similar problem like **No handles with labels found to put in legend.**

First My code look like

```
figure, axis = pyplot.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=2, figsize=(15, 6), tight_layout=True)

axis[0].legend(title='Country', title_fontsize = 12) #this line
axis[0].pie(x=piechart_result['value_eur'],labels=piechart_result['short_name'])

axis[1].pie(x=piechart_result['value_eur'],labels=piechart_result['short_name')

pyplot.show()
```

Then I changed to

```
figure, axis = pyplot.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=2, figsize=(15, 6), tight_layout=True)

axis[0].pie(x=piechart_result['value_eur'],labels=piechart_result['short_name'])
axis[0].legend(title='Country', title_fontsize = 12) # this line 

axis[1].pie(x=piechart_result['value_eur'],labels=piechart_result['short_name')

pyplot.show()
```

this work for me in colab notebook

Answer (score -1):

I had this same issue and solved it with an understanding that `.legend()` function has to be after all the instructions that deal with the label attribute. This includes both `plt` and `ax`.

So moving `ax.legend(*)` as the last command.

I hope this helps you too.

Change

```py
ax.plot(-trip_df.stop_lat, -trip_df.stop_lon, label = trip_id)
plt.legend()
```

to

```py
ax.plot(-trip_df.stop_lat, -trip_df.stop_lon, label = trip_id)
ax.legend()
plt.legend()
```