# Plotting Area plots with x axis formatting

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following code:

```
population = pd.DataFrame(data = population)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10, 5))
population.columns = ['pop']
# ax.area(population['pop'], kind ='area')
# ax = population.plot.area()


ax.fill_between: ax.fill_between(population.index, population['pop'], alpha=0.3, label='Population')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(md.YearLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%Y'))
plt.setp(ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation = 90)
ax.set_xlim([population.index[0], population.index[-1]])
ax.fill_between(population['pop'],0)
```

This makes the following plot:

[image]

How can i plot an area plot. If i do this:

```
ax.plot(population['pop'], kind ='area')
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Line2D' object has no property 'kind'
```

If i do this:

```
ax = population.plot.area()
```

[image]

It leaves the entire formatting on the x-axis. How can i plot area?
Edit:

I get the following plot
[image]

### For legend:

I added the following line:

```
ax.fill_between: ax.fill_between(population.index, population['pop'], alpha=0.3, label='Population')
```

[image]

As you can see there is no legend

Comment: Try `ax.fill_between(population.index, population['pop'],0)` in your first solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `ax.plot()`, use `ax.fill_between()`:

```
plt.fill_between(your_x_list, your_y_list, label=your_label)
```

Comment: It worked but it is still not showing legend. What can i do to get the label?

Comment: Can you post the result?

Comment: @Slartibartfast You need to call `ax.legend()` to see the legend

Comment: @JohanC It prompts: `No handles with labels found to put in legend.`

Comment: @Slartibartfast You can see https://stackoverflow.com/q/59346731/13552470

Comment: You need to set a label in the call to `ax.plot` and/or `ax.fill_between`: `ax.fill_between(population.index, population['pop'], alpha=0.3, label='Population')`

Comment: @JohanC There is no legend that shows up. I have also updated the code.

Comment: @AnnZen `ax.legend([population], ['population'])` Even with this there is no legend

Comment: @Slartibartfast You need to call `plt.legend()`, with no parameters.