# WARNING:matplotlib.legend:No handles with labels found to put in legend

Tags: python, python-3.x

The chart has been created but the legend is not showing and facing the error as **"WARNING:matplotlib.legend: No handles with labels found to put in legend."**

Comment: Here is a duplicate, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59346731/no-handles-with-labels-found-to-put-in-legend

Comment: I thought self.xticks is showing value as "0" thats only I am facing the issue.                  tp_count = len(time_points) **=> 1**
        xtick_label_stepsize = tp_count / 15 **=> 0.06666666666666667**
        if xtick_label_stepsize == 0:
            xtick_label_stepsize = 1
        self.x_data = range(tp_count) **=> range(0,1)**
        self.xticks = np.arange(0, tp_count, xtick_label_stepsize,dtype=int) **=> 0**

Comment: I have already seen but not the same. In Visualization, I am using the below code. Here self.xticks is zero                                                                         plt.xticks(self.xticks,self.xtick_labels,rotation=Visualization.PLT_XTICK_LABEL_ROTATION)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No handles with labels found to put in legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59346731/no-handles-with-labels-found-to-put-in-legend)