# No handles with labels found to put in legend linechart

Tags: matplotlib, charts, legend

I'm plotting a line chart using matplotlib. In all others, it usually autodetects the legend, but I've used a pivot table to plot the chart this time, which I think is stopping it. I'm unsure how to plot the legend as a result.

```
No handles with labels found to put in legend.
```

My code is as follows;

```
x = t['month'].unique()
y = t.pivot(index='month', columns='T_Name', values='HIR_Won')[t['T_Name'].unique()] 
  
#n = len(t['T_Name'].unique())
ax = plt.axes(label=data.index)
ax.legend()
ax.set_prop_cycle('color',[plt.cm.Greens(i) for i in np.linspace(0, 1, n)])

for i in range(n):
    plt.plot(x, y)
```

[image]

Added a label arg

```
#n = len(t['T_Name'].unique())
ax = plt.axes()
ax.set_prop_cycle('color',[plt.cm.Greens(i) for i in np.linspace(0, 1, n)])

for i in range(n):
    plt.plot(x, y, label=y.columns)

ax.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: You should move `ax.legend` after all the plots. Plus, pass `label='some_label'` to `plt.plot(x,y)`.

Comment: I think the way the pivot is constructed when I add a label constraint I don't get a single name mapped to each plot. See the updated post.

Comment: Maybe you want to call `plt.plot(x, y, label=y.columns[i])`?

Comment: Could you clean up the example code? It doesn't make sense to have a loop over `i` when you constantly plot the same `x` and `y`. Also, the image shows something like `label=y.index`, not `label=y.columns`

Comment: Yes, as the label, you should have just one per loop step. Try it out with just a test, replace y.columns with i. This error is all about adding a label to the plt.plot(), so that you have plt.plot(x, y, label=SOME_LABEL_FOR_CURRENT_LOOP_STEP).

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a

```
plt.plot(x, y, label=SOME_SINGLE_LABEL_FOR_CURRENT_LOOP_STEP)
```

to be able to call

```
plt.legend()
```

afterwards. If you do not add the label arg, you cannot call plt.legend(), since it does not know what to print in the legend.

In your case, you want to loop through all of the names in that index and make each name the current label of a step.

So the solution is obvious and almost there (and was hinted at also in the comments):

```
ax = plt.axes()
ax.set_prop_cycle('color',[plt.cm.Greens(i) for i in np.linspace(0, 1, n)])

cols = list(y.columns)
for i in range(n):
    plt.plot(x, y, label=cols[i])

ax.legend()
```

At least, I could also get rid of the error by just adding the label arg, which is so simple, but which was hard to find on Stack Overflow.