# No handles with labels found to put in legend error after plotting two plots on one chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm plotting some features month by month and highlighted some of them. Before I added the highlight, the legend can show automatically but now it returns `No handles with labels found to put in legend` error.

Example data

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
highlight = ['A', 'B']
```

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 5))
plt.plot(df.loc[:, ~df.columns.isin(highlight)], c='gray', alpha=0.5) 
plt.plot(df.loc[:, df.columns.isin(highlight)]) 
months = pd.date_range('2019-04-01','2019-08-01', freq='MS').strftime("%Y-%m").tolist()
plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5))
z = ax.set_xticklabels(months, rotation=45)
```

[image]

I guess plotting two plots on one chart caused this but don't know how to fix it. I don't want to manually specify legends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) instead of `plt.plot`

  - This ensures the column headers are correctly assigned as the labels to the correct line
  - It returns a [`matplotlib.axes.Axes`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes) or a `numpy.ndarray` of them.
- This example is using `pandas v1.2.3`

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = df.loc[:, df.columns.isin(highlight)].plot(figsize=(15, 5))
df.loc[:, ~df.columns.isin(highlight)].plot(c='gray', alpha=0.5, ax=ax)

plt.legend(title='column labels', loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Simply switch the order of your plt.plot() statements and declare your legend items explicitly like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
highlight = ['A', 'B']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 5))
plt.plot(df.loc[:, df.columns.isin(highlight)])
plt.plot(df.loc[:, ~df.columns.isin(highlight)], c='gray', alpha=0.5)
months = pd.date_range('2019-04-01','2019-09-01', freq='MS').strftime("%Y-%m").tolist()
plt.legend(list('ABCD'),loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5))
z = ax.set_xticklabels(months, rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of that error by adding a label parameter whenever you `plt.plot(...,label=...)`, same solution at [No handles with labels found to put in legend linechart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68339402/11154841).

When running your code, I get another error in addition, but that is not part of the question and answer here.

> No handles with labels found to put in legend.
> :13: UserWarning: FixedFormatter should
> only be used together with FixedLocator   z =
> ax.set_xticklabels(months, rotation=45)

I added label='test' and label='test2' as a start.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
highlight = ['A', 'B']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 5))
plt.plot(df.loc[:, ~df.columns.isin(highlight)], c='gray', alpha=0.5, label='test')
plt.plot(df.loc[:, df.columns.isin(highlight)], label='test2')
months = pd.date_range('2019-04-01','2019-08-01', freq='MS').strftime("%Y-%m").tolist()
plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5))
z = ax.set_xticklabels(months, rotation=45)
```

The error is gone.

What is still left is only the error that was there anyway and which is not linked with the question:

```
<ipython-input-78-5f152143ed24>:13: UserWarning: FixedFormatter should only be used together with FixedLocator
  z = ax.set_xticklabels(months, rotation=45)
```